# Redirection to parent route instead of child on page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

```
{
        path: '',
        component: componentA,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: componentB,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'upload',
                component: UploadComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'step_1',
                        component: StepOneComponent,
                        pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'step_2',
                        component: StepTwoComponent,
                        pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                    ...
```

**Current behavior:**

In `ngOnInit()` of `UploadComponent` I do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.router.navigateTo(['step_1']);
}
```

If you are on the `StepTwoComponent` and do refresh page you are being redirected to `StepOneComponent`.

I assume that this happens because firstly `UploadComponent` is being loaded, which redirects to `StepOneComponent` instead of current.

`UploadComponent.html` consists of:

```
<div>
       <!-- some content -->
</div>

<div>
       <!-- some content -->

       <router-outlet></router-outlet>

       <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

**Question:**

How to make a refresh to no redirect to `StepOneComponent` but to current one?

Comment: You can store actual route in localStorage, for ex. localStorage.setItem('route', 'step_2'); and then in ngOnInit() get this route and navigate

Answer (score 0):

Register the routes `''` (not full) and `'**'` (wild card routes) in the children so they navigate to `step_1`:

```
{
        path: '',
        component: componentA,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: componentB,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'upload',
                component: UploadComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'step_1',
                        component: StepOneComponent,
                        pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'step_2',
                        component: StepTwoComponent,
                        pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                    // put these 2 new routes at the end
                    {
                     path: '',
                     redirectTo: 'step_1',
                     pathMatch: 'full',
                    },
                    {
                     path: '**',
                     redirectTo: 'step_1',
                     pathMatch: 'full',
                    }....
```

In `ngOnInit` of `UploadComponent`, remove the logic to navigate to `'step_1'`.

Now, when you refresh when on `step_2`, you should stay on `step_2`.

Comment: i think the order is important: `path: ''` should come first and the wildcard at last

Comment: Yes order is important, put those 2 new routes at the bottom.